# Recurrence Relation with two parameters and Summation

Tags: summation, recurrence-relations, markov-chains

This is a recurrence relation with two parameters which came up in a problem I was trying to solve.

> Given
>   $$\begin{align}&A_n=pB_{n-1};\qquad &&B_n=q(A_{n-1}+B_{n-1})\\
> &A_4=p; \qquad &&B_4=q; \\
> &p+q=1;&&(0< p,q< 1)\end{align}$$
>   evaluate
>   $$\sum_{n=4}^\infty n(A_n+B_n)$$

From the above it can be seen that 
$$A_n+B_n=q(A_{n-2}+B_{n-2})+pqB_{n-2}$$
and also that 
$$B_n-B_{n-1}=qA_{n-1}-A_n$$
but it is not clear how these can help with the required summation. Logically one should first attempt to express $A_n, B_n$ explicitly in terns of $n$.

Altenratively the original recurrence equation can be represented as

$$\left(\begin{matrix}A_{n}\\B_n\end{matrix}\right)
=\left(\begin{matrix}0&p\\1-p&1-p\end{matrix}\right)
\left(\begin{matrix}A_{n-1}\\B_{n-1}\end{matrix}\right)$$
Suggestions on how to proceed would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

From your own calculations, notice that you may write

$$\begin{pmatrix} A_n \\ B_n \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & p \\ q & q  \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} A_{n-1} \\ B_{n-1} \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & p \\ q & q  \end{pmatrix}^2 \begin{pmatrix} A_{n-2} \\ B_{n-2} \end{pmatrix} = \dots = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & p \\ q & q  \end{pmatrix}^{n-4} \begin{pmatrix} A_4 \\ B_4 \end{pmatrix} \ \forall n \ge 4 .$$

Let $M = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & p \\ q & q  \end{pmatrix}$.

Notice that $A_n + B_n$ can be identified with the $1 \times 1$ matrix

$$\begin{pmatrix} A_n + B_n \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} A_n \\ B_n \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix} M^{n-4} \begin{pmatrix} A_4 \\ B_4 \end{pmatrix} ,$$

therefore, if you place your sum inside a $1 \times 1$ matrix, it becomes

$$(A_4 + B_4) + \sum \limits _{n \ge 5} n \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix} M^{n-4} \begin{pmatrix} A_4 \\ B_4 \end{pmatrix} = (1) + \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix} \sum \limits _{n \ge 5} n M^{n-4} \begin{pmatrix} A_4 \\ B_4 \end{pmatrix} = \\
(1) + \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix} \sum \limits _{k \ge 1} (k+4) M^k \begin{pmatrix} A_4 \\ B_4 \end{pmatrix} = \\
(1) + \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix} \sum \limits _{k \ge 1} k M^k \begin{pmatrix} A_4 \\ B_4 \end{pmatrix} + 4 \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix} \sum \limits _{k \ge 1} M^k \begin{pmatrix} A_4 \\ B_4 \end{pmatrix} .$$

The usual formulae for numbers are valid for matrices too, i.e.

$$\sum \limits _{k \ge 1} M^k = M (1-M)^{-1}, \qquad \sum \limits _{k \ge 1} k M^k = M (1-M)^{-2}$$

therefore your sum (as a matrix) becomes

$$(1) + \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix} M (1 - M)^{-1} \begin{pmatrix} A_4 \\ B_4 \end{pmatrix} + 4 \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix} M (1 - M)^{-2} \begin{pmatrix} A_4 \\ B_4 \end{pmatrix} .$$

It is easy to compute $(1-M)^{-1} = \frac 1 {p^2} \begin{pmatrix} p & p \\ q & 1 \end{pmatrix}$, so $(1-M)^{-2} = \frac 1 {p^4} \begin{pmatrix} p & p^2 + p \\ pq + q & pq + 1 \end{pmatrix}$, whence everything follows (honestly, I don not feel like performing matrix multiplications, it seems to me that you are more than able to finish this).

Comment: interesting solution! (+1) Didn't realise that you can sum powers of matrices in the same way as a geometric series or its derivative. Thanks!

Comment: @hypergeometric: Those formulae are valid in any Banach algebra, provided that $\| M \| < 1$.

Answer (score 1):

This corresponds to a process which can be in state $A$ or $B$; if it's in state $B$, it stays in state $B$ with probability $q$ and transitions to state $A$ with probability $p$; if it's in state $A$ it transitions to state $B$ with probability $q$ and ends with probability $p$.

Consider the sum

$$
\sum_{n=4}^\infty(A_n+B_n)t^{n-4}\;.
$$

This is the expected duration of the above process, measured from $n=4$, when all non-terminal probabilities are multiplied by $t$. With $E_A$ and $E_B$ the expected remaining durations when the process is in state $A$ and $B$, respectively, we have

\begin{align}
E_A&=1+qtE_B\;,\\
E_B&=1+qtE_B+ptE_A\;,
\end{align}

and substituting $E_A$ from the first equation into the second yields

\begin{align}
E_B&=\frac{1+pt}{1-qt-pqt^2}\;,\\
E_A&=\frac1{1-qt-pqt^2}\;.
\end{align}

As the process starts at $n=4$ in state $A$ with probability $p$ and in state $B$ with probability $q$, we have

\begin{align}
\sum_{n=4}^\infty(A_n+B_n)t^n&=t^4\sum_{n=4}^\infty(A_n+B_n)t^{n-4}\\
&=t^4\left(pE_A+qE_b\right)\\
&=t^4\frac{p+q+pqt}{1-qt-pqt^2}\\
&=t^4\frac{1+pqt}{1-qt-pqt^2}\;.
\end{align}

Then differentiating with respect to $t$ and setting $t=1$ yields

\begin{align}
\sum_{n=4}^\infty n(A_n+B_n)&=\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}\left.\left(t^4\frac{1+pqt}{1-qt-pqt^2}\right)\right|_{t=1}\\
&=\frac1{p^4}+\frac2{p^3}+\frac2{p^2}+\frac2p-3\;.
\end{align}

Comment: Nice solution... you rightly guessed that the problem is related to probabilities! Thanks! (+1)

Comment: Could you please explain further about (i) multiplying with $t$, and what $t$ represents (is it $\delta t$?) (ii) how the equations for $E_A, E_B$ are derived?

Comment: @hypergeometric: (i) Multiplying by $t^n$ is a trick so that we can differentiate with respect to $t$ to get the factor $n$. If $A_n+B_n$ is the probability that the process is still alive at time $n$, then $(A_n+B_n)t^n$ is the probability that the process is still alive at time $n$ if we give it an extra probability $t$ of ending in each step. Thus the modified sum is the expected duration of a process in which all transition probabilities to non-terminal states are reduced by a factor $t$. (No, it's not $\delta t$, it's just some parameter, I didn't mean to imply $t$ for "time".)

Comment: @hypergeometric: (ii) This is a so-called one-step analysis or first-step analysis. If the process is in state $A$, it takes one step no matter what happens -- that's the $1$. Then with probability $qt$ it goes to state $B$, where it takes another expected $E_B$ steps, and with probability $1-qt$ it ends, so no more steps in that case. And likewise for $E_B$, except here we have two non-terminal transition options.

Comment: Thanks for taking the trouble to explain in detail. Will think through your explanation. The original problem is related to coin-flipping and can be solved easily by first-step analysis. I formulated the recursion as I wanted to see how it can also be solved by summation, but somehow the summation doesn't turn out to be a neat one...

Comment: @hypergeometric: Well, the matrix doesn't have nice eigenvalues; that makes it all a bit fiddly. I guess if you reformulate a problem and someone reformulates it back close to the original formulation to solve it, that's a strong indication that the reformulation may not have constituted much progress :-)